# npm coffescript install error

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm

```
I keep having errors when trying to install coffeescript.  
node version v0.6.1
npm version 1.0.106

npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm
npm ERR! error installing coffee-script@1.1.3 Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm'
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Thomas
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___coffee-script.npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Thomas/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

The permission is denied and I have found that you should not sudo.
 Please help and thanks in advance.

---

OKay all solved with the help of sudo but if anyone has any idea how to change my /usr/local/lib permissions it would be appriciated

Comment: yeah, I'm not sure if NPM works with Node 0.6 yet.

Comment: I think the NPM works but it is like a file permission error or something. dunno plz help

Comment: I sudo installed it and it worked no problem.  If anyone has a different solution though it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is:

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`

That way, you can install whatever you want in `/usr/local` without sudoing :)